Faithful weights determined by their one-parameter automorphism group?
I am reading through a paper on KMS weights that makes mention of the following (somewhat fundamental in my opinion) observation.

Let $\varphi$ be a faithful weight (I will assume for simplicity that $\varphi$ is just a positive faithful linear functional) on a $C^{*}$-algebra $A$ with one-parameter automorphism group $\sigma: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(A)$.  Then the equations: $$\varphi(xy)= \varphi(y\sigma_{-i}(x)), \: \: \varphi(\sigma_t(x)) = \varphi(x), \: \: \forall x,y \in A \: t \in \mathbb{R}$$ uniquely determine $\sigma$.

My interpretation of this is that if $\eta: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(A)$ is any other group homomorphism satisfying:
$$\varphi(xy)= \varphi(y\eta_{-i}(x)), \: \: \varphi(\eta_t(x)) = \varphi(x), \: \: \forall x,y \in A \: t \in \mathbb{R}$$ then $\eta = \sigma$.  If this interpretation is incorrect, please correct me!
Now, it's clear to me that the first equation implies $\eta_{-i} = \sigma_{-i}$ by faithfulness of $\varphi$, since you get for $x \in A$: $$\varphi(y[\eta_{-i}(x) - \sigma_{-i}(x)]) = 0 \: \: \forall y \in A.$$ However I don't see how one uses the second equation to prove $\eta = \sigma$.  In particular, I feel like some additional lemma or something is needed to solve this (something perhaps like if $\eta_{-i} = \sigma_{-i}$ then infact $\eta = \sigma$, i'm not sure).
If anyone can point me to a reference that has a proof of this fact, or if you can provide a proof of this, that would be highly appreciated!

Can you add the exact paper that you are working on?

Kind of, it does require a login to see the entire paper: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11376569_2 .  In particular this comment is from pg 134.

I can't find the comment to which you are referring.  Could you be more specific?
